# how to split a string column into 4 string columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have definition column of a medication. I want the definition to be split into `[product name(PN)]`, `[doseform(DF)]`, `[total dose(TD)]` and `[units]`.
Eg:

```
BENADRYL: MYLANTA 1:1 SOLUTION(Benadryl mylanta(PN),Sol(DF),1:1(TD),NULL(units))
MASK AND SPACER (Mark and Spacer(PN),NUll,NUll,NUll)
BL VITAMIN B-6 50 MG  TABS(BL Vitamin(PN),Tabs(DF),50(TD),MG(Units))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few assumptions about your data. 1 is that the first opening bracket begins the definition ie. there are no brackets in the name before the definition. I am also assuming the the product definition structure will not change.

So, to get to your answer, I have used a modified split string function. I used this one as a base: [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

The difference here is that the function will return a 2 column table so we can identify the definition parts

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring_custom
  (
   @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX)
  )
RETURNS @returnList TABLE
  (
   [Type] [nvarchar](20)
  ,[Name] [nvarchar](500)
  )
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @colidx INT = 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0 
          BEGIN
                SELECT  @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
                SELECT  @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos - 1)

                INSERT  INTO @returnList
                        SELECT  CASE WHEN @colidx = 1 THEN 'Product Name'
                                     WHEN @colidx = 2 THEN 'Dose Form'
                                     WHEN @colidx = 3 THEN 'Total Dose'
                                     WHEN @colidx = 4 THEN 'Units'
                                END
                               ,@name

                SELECT  @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos + 1, LEN(@stringToSplit) - @pos)
                SET @colidx += 1
          END

    INSERT  INTO @returnList
            SELECT  CASE WHEN @colidx = 1 THEN 'Product Name'
                         WHEN @colidx = 2 THEN 'Dose Form'
                         WHEN @colidx = 3 THEN 'Total Dose'
                         WHEN @colidx = 4 THEN 'Units'
                    END
                   ,@stringToSplit

    RETURN
END
```

Then we get the relevant part of the definition using some string manipulation:

```
SUBSTRING(medication, CHARINDEX('(', medication) + 1, LEN(medication) - (CHARINDEX('(', medication) + 1))
```

Then [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the results to flatten it out:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id varchar(20), medication varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('BENADRYL', 'BENADRYL: MYLANTA 1:1 SOLUTION(Benadryl mylanta(PN),Sol(DF),1:1(TD),NULL(units))')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('MASK', 'MASK AND SPACER (Mark and Spacer(PN),NULL,NULL,NULL)')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('BL VITAMIN', 'BL VITAMIN B-6 50 MG  TABS(BL Vitamin(PN),Tabs(DF),50(TD),MG(Units))')

SELECT  id, [Product Name], [Dose Form], [Total Dose], [Units]
FROM    (SELECT id, Type, Name
         FROM   @t t
         CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring_custom(SUBSTRING(medication, CHARINDEX('(', medication) + 1, LEN(medication) - (CHARINDEX('(', medication) + 1)))
        ) X PIVOT ( MAX(Name) FOR TYPE IN ([Product Name], [Dose Form], [Total Dose], [Units]) ) pvt
```